# How can I view the remaining changesets left to check in an hg bisect?

Tags: mercurial, bisect

When I'm running hg bisect, sometimes I want to "look ahead" at what's remaining, to see if there are any obvious culprits I could check while a fairly slow bisection test runs.

So given I've run

```
> hg bisect -g
Testing changeset 15802:446defa0e64a (8 changesets remaining, ~2 tests)
```

How can I view which 8 changesets are remaining?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `bisect("untested")` revset to view the untested changesets. E.g.:

```
hg log -r 'bisect(untested)'
```

If that is too much information, you can also combine it with a template option:

```
hg log -r 'bisect(untested)' -T '{rev}\n'
```

Or you can just restrict the output to the first and last entry of the range:

```
hg log -r 'first(bisect(untested))+last(bisect(untested))'
```

You can also create revset aliases in your `.hg/hgrc` or `~/.hgrc` file to save some typing, e.g.:

```
[revsetalias]
tbt = bisect("untested")
tbt2 = first(tbt)+last(tbt)
```

Then you can do (for example):

```
hg log -r tbt
```

Note that if you call a revset alias `untested`, you'll have to quote the string untested (e.g. `bisect("untested")`), hence my choice of `tbt` (for "to be tested").

See `hg help revsets` for more revsets pertaining to bisection.